# How to map JSON object to collapsed rows in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an JSON object coming from the database as one big object e.g:

```
 $scope.totalsum =
      {
           "A1": 1155000,
           "A2": null,
           "A3": 2133,
           "A31": 29292,
           "A32": 2321,
           "A33": 232342,
           etc....
      },
```

I need to have the A31 & A32 etc to populate a collapsed table data row. Here is the ng-repeat for object so far:

```
 <tr ng-repeat-start="data in totalsum" ng-click="isRowCollapsed=!isRowCollapsed">
      <td>
           <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{data.total | number:2}}">
      </td>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="data.breakdown.length>0" ng-hide="isRowCollapsed">
      <td ng-show="data.breakdown.length>0">
           <div class="subvalues" ng-repeat="subvalues in data.breakdown">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{subvalues.subtotal | number:2}}">
           </div>
      </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>
           <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{getTotal('total') | number:2}}">
      </td>
 </tr>
```

I initially had the ng-repeat working for a JSON object like this:

```
 $scope.totalsum = [
                     {
                          "total": 1155000,
                          "breakdown": null
                      },
                      {
                          "total": 233235000,
                          "breakdown": [
                              {
                                  "subtotal": 22002020
                              },
                              {
                                  "subtotal": 22002020
                              }
                          ]
                      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know you can use ng-repeat with (key, value) option to solve this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in totalsum">
     <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: the problem is that the object coming from the database is just a one level JSON script. I need to map anything that is A12 A13 A14 , A21 A22 A23 etc to a collapsed table data row